# How can I set paperclip's storage mechanism based on the current Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a rails application that has multiple models with paperclip attachments that are all uploaded to S3.  This app also has a large test suite that is run quite often. The downside with this is that a ton of files are uploaded to our S3 account on every test run, making the test suite run slowly.  It also slows down development a bit, and requires you to have an internet connection in order to work on the code.

Is there a reasonable way to set the paperclip storage mechanism based on the Rails environment? Ideally, our test and development environments would use the local filesystem storage, and the production environment would use S3 storage.

I'd also like to extract this logic into a shared module of some kind, since we have several models that will need this behavior. I'd like to avoid a solution like this inside of every model:

```
### We don't want to do this in our models...
if Rails.env.production?
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => {...},
                    :path => "images/:uuid_partition/:uuid/:style.:extension",
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :url => ':s3_authenticated_url', # generates an expiring url
                    :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml'),
                    :s3_permissions => 'private',
                    :s3_protocol => 'https'
else
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => {...},
                    :storage => :filesystem
                    # Default :path and :url should be used for dev/test envs.
end
```

**Update:** The sticky part is that the attachment's `:path` and `:url` options need to differ depending on which storage system is being used.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After playing around with it for a while, I came up with a module that does what I want.

Inside `app/models/shared/attachment_helper.rb`:

```
module Shared
  module AttachmentHelper

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def has_attachment(name, options = {})

        # generates a string containing the singular model name and the pluralized attachment name.
        # Examples: "user_avatars" or "asset_uploads" or "message_previews"
        attachment_owner    = self.table_name.singularize
        attachment_folder   = "#{attachment_owner}_#{name.to_s.pluralize}"

        # we want to create a path for the upload that looks like:
        # message_previews/00/11/22/001122deadbeef/thumbnail.png
        attachment_path     = "#{attachment_folder}/:uuid_partition/:uuid/:style.:extension"

        if Rails.env.production?
          options[:path]            ||= attachment_path
          options[:storage]         ||= :s3
          options[:url]             ||= ':s3_authenticated_url'
          options[:s3_credentials]  ||= File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml')
          options[:s3_permissions]  ||= 'private'
          options[:s3_protocol]     ||= 'https'
        else
          # For local Dev/Test envs, use the default filesystem, but separate the environments
          # into different folders, so you can delete test files without breaking dev files.
          options[:path]  ||= ":rails_root/public/system/attachments/#{Rails.env}/#{attachment_path}"
          options[:url]   ||= "/system/attachments/#{Rails.env}/#{attachment_path}"
        end

        # pass things off to paperclip.
        has_attached_file name, options
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*(Note: I'm using some custom paperclip interpolations above, like `:uuid_partition`, `:uuid` and `:s3_authenticated_url`. You'll need to modify things as needed for your particular application)*

Now, for every model that has paperclip attachments, you just have to include this shared module, and call the `has_attachment` method (instead of paperclip's `has_attached_file`)

An example model file: `app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Shared::AttachmentHelper  
  has_attachment :avatar, :styles => { :thumbnail => "100x100>" }
end
```

With this in place, you'll have files saved to the following locations, depending on your environment:

**Development:**

`RAILS_ROOT + public/attachments/development/user_avatars/aa/bb/cc/aabbccddeeff/thumbnail.jpg`

**Test:**

`RAILS_ROOT + public/attachments/test/user_avatars/aa/bb/cc/aabbccddeeff/thumbnail.jpg`

**Production:**

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/your-bucket-name/user_avatars/aa/bb/cc/aabbccddeeff/thumbnail.jpg`

This does exactly what I'm looking for, hopefully it'll prove useful to someone else too. :)

-John

Comment: Good work. Yes, a lot more abstraction was needed than I provided! :)

Comment: I was having trouble with the constant/hash method mentioned above, but this works great, and I like how I can keep all my paperclip logic in one place. Thanks!

Answer (score 78):

I like Barry's suggestion better and there's nothing keeping you from setting the variable to a hash, that can then be merged with the paperclip options.

In config/environments/development.rb and test.rb set something like

```
PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS = {}
```

And in config/environments/production.rb

```
PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS = {:storage => :s3, 
                               :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                               :path => "/:style/:filename"}
```

Finally in your paperclip model:

```
has_attached_file :image, {
    :styles => {:thumb => '50x50#', :original => '800x800>'}
}.merge(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)
```

**Update:** A similar approach was recently [implemented in Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/efead1a179383e049a996f9d4ed6ae1d7ed8e9e7) for Rails 3.x apps. Environment specific settings can now be set with `config.paperclip_defaults = {:storage => :s3, ...}`.

Answer (score 32):

You can set global default configuration data in the environment-specific configuration files.  For example, in config/environments/production.rb:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => 'wheresmahbucket',
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
})
```

Comment: Less meta, more explicit, definitely the way to go. This could even be extracted into a YAML file with a namespace per environment. Thanks @austinfromboston

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

1. Defaults are established in application.rb.  The default storage of :filesystem is used, but the configuration for s3 is initialized
2. Production.rb enables :s3 storage and changes the default path

Application.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = 
{
  :hash_secret => "LongSecretString",
  :s3_protocol => "https",
  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/aws_config.yml",
  :styles => { 
    :original => "1024x1024>",
    :large => "600x600>", 
    :medium => "300x300>",
    :thumb => "100x100>" 
  }
}
```

Development.rb (uncomment this to try with s3 in development mode)

```
# config.paperclip_defaults.merge!({
#   :storage => :s3,
#   :bucket => "mydevelopmentbucket",
#   :path => ":hash.:extension"
# })
```

Production.rb:

```
config.paperclip_defaults.merge!({
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => "myproductionbucket",
  :path => ":hash.:extension"
})
```

In your model:

```
has_attached_file :avatar
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just set an environment variable in production/test/development.rb?

```
PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_MECHANISM = :s3
```

Then:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {...},
                  :storage => PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_MECHANISM,
                  # ...etc...
```

Comment: Hey Barry, 

That's a good suggestion, but the various options inside of the "...etc..." cause trouble. I discovered that the :path and :url options need to differ depending on whether it's using :s3 or :filesystem storage. 

I'll update the question with a better example.  

Thanks,  --John

Answer (score 0):

My solution is same with @runesoerensen answer:

I create a module `PaperclipStorageOption` in `config/initializers/paperclip_storage_option.rb`
The code is very simple:

```
module PaperclipStorageOption
  module ClassMethods
    def options
      Rails.env.production? ? production_options : default_options
    end

    private

    def production_options
      {
        storage: :dropbox,
        dropbox_credentials: Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml")
      }
    end

    def default_options
      {}
    end
  end

  extend ClassMethods
end
```

and use it in our model
`has_attached_file :avatar, { :styles => { :medium => "1200x800>" } }.merge(PaperclipStorageOption.options)`

Just it, hope this help

Answer (score -4):

Use the :rails_env interpolation when you define the attachment path:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :path => ":rails_root/storage/:rails_env/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```