# Accessing ApplicationHelper from User.rb model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

Here's some simple code that isn't working:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def industries
    industries = ['Agriculture','Food', etc.]
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
  validates_inclusion_of :industries, :in => ApplicationHelper.industries
  ...
end
```

This code is failing when a user action is run with `undefined method 'industries'`. Do you know how I can reference the helper (or preferably just industries) the right way?

---

#### Edit

Based on the code in Mauricio's answer below, how can `INDUSTRIES` be accessed in a controller and a view? I'm having real trouble making industries accessible everywhere, but it really needs to be for my application.

Answer (score 7):

You should **never** do something like this. ApplicationHelper is not supposed to be included in a model. Best solution would be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    INDUSTRIES = ['Agriculture','Food']
    validates_inclusion_of :industries, :in => INDUSTRIES
end

module ApplicationHelper
    def industries
        User::INDUSTRIES
    end
end
```

And now you have it done in a simple and nice way.

**EDIT**

Anywhere you need to access industries you should use:

```
User::INDUSTRIES
```

And that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mauricio - could you tell me why I should never do what I was trying to do?

Comment: Also, how can I now access industries from my view?

Comment: Mauricio's answer sounds like the way to go. It might help you in future to know that you can also put globals in `config/application.rb` or any of the environment files. It's common to see people doing this when the info is not model specific - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562249/how-can-i-set-paperclips-storage-mechanism-based-on-the-current-rails-environme

Comment: I have an analogous situation. When I follow Mauricio's answer, Rspec crashes:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/
core/configuration.rb:698: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Comment: I should note that one of the spec/support files includes ApplicationHelper.

Comment: There's probably something different in your spec that's causing this "stack level too deep". This usually means that there is a method eternally calling itself.

Comment: It happens only when I apply your solution. When my equivalent of industries (states and countries) are defined in ApplicationHelper.rb and I include ApplicationHelper just before the model class in the model file then Rspec runs fine. When I move the code to the model file and remove the includes as you detail, Rspec crashes.

Comment: I decided to start over and try it again, and now it works. Must have gotten something wrong. Is adding `industries` to ApplicationHelper there to make it available in the views?

Comment: @GeorgeShaw it will, all views.