# Rails 4, Paperclip, Amazon S3 - Upload to a specific folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

This is the first time I'm using Paperclip and Amazon S3 and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious. It would be great if somebody can point it out.

In S3 bucket, I have 2 folders, **development** and **production**, to upload images to corresponding folders based on the environment. I tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562249/how-can-i-set-paperclips-storage-mechanism-based-on-the-current-rails-environme) as follows in my `model.rb` -

```
options = {}

if Rails.env.production?
   options[:path] ||= 'production'
else
   options[:path] ||= 'development'
end

has_attached_file :picture, options
```

I kept getting a file named **development** / **production** uploaded to the S3 bucket (as shown in the screenshot).

[image]

I even tried passing the `:path` as config setting for paperclip. Same thing happened - a folder named development / production was getting uploaded

Am I missing something here? All I want to do, upload pictures I get in the development environment into the development folder and vice versa for production.

Comment: Try adding a slash after production i.e. `options[:path] ||= 'production/``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path option needs to specify the file pattern as well. Try this

#### Model

```
has_attached_file :picture,
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => 'your_bucket',
  :path => ":env_folder/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename.:extension"

# some other model code here ...

private

# interpolate in paperclip
Paperclip.interpolates :env_folder  do |attachment, style|
  Rails.env.production? ? 'production' : 'development'
end
```

#### EDIT

If you just leave the `:path` option as 'development' or 'production' you're telling Paperclip the path to the file is `yourbucket/development` which is why you're seeing the single file as per your screenshot. This is why it's important to have something that will uniquely identify the resource in the `:path` option (I used `:id` in my example which will use the model's id attribute).

If you have the option, I think a better approach would be to separate the environments into their own buckets. In other words, the `development` environment would have its own bucket and `production` would have its own separate bucket. Not only is this cleaner within the code, you'll also be able to set different policies per bucket/environment which in my experience is required once your app is released in production. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't get why there needs to be an extension in the path. I basically want all the pictures (jpg, png etc.) to be uploaded to that specific folder in my S3 bucket. The path basically specifies the folder structure within the S3 bucket, correct?

Comment: I agree separating the environments into their own buckets makes it cleaner. But with S3 being so popular, I was wondering if there'd be an easier way to do folder level separation.

Comment: @AswinRamakrishnan the `:extension` in my example is just for illustrative purposes, you can omit it if you don't want it as part of the URI. The `path` option specifies the path to the uploaded file which is why you can't just have 'production' or 'development' as in your original post. If you just had 'development' then the actual name of the uploaded file would be 'development' as in your attached screenshot.

Comment: @AswinRamakrishnan in regards to popularity and the fact that S3 buckets have to be unique, I found a good solution is to namespace your buckets with your application name. For example, `myapp.prod` and `myapp.development`.

Comment: 10-4 on the path option! As you can tell - S3 Noob :) I like namespacing the buckets option. Just curious - by namespacing the buckets, do you get any app level isolation? Or is it more of a convention thing?

Comment: @AswinRamakrishnan it's simply a convention. Please accept my answer if you found it helpful. Cheers.